# RadioButtons in Angular 6 FormArrays - maintaining the structure of form.value

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get along with FormArrays and radio buttons in Angular 6, and somehow cannot get what I want.

I want to initialize the form values based on JSON-like object (server response) - this part is mostly working - and at the same time - **get the same object structure back** - which is where I have problem.

Instead I see the `form.value` changes the supplied property from boolean to string (an option's id).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-radio

I also want to be able to patch a value onto an existing form, such as for editing.

I would like to do it in a declarative and reactive way, without resorting to `ngModel` or other mixing of techniques - if possible.

What/Where am I doing wrong?, please help me before I `yarn add ng-formly` in desperation...

Answer (score 0):

You can add the fields that you want in the final value of the form in the `buildSkills` and `buildLevels` methods:

```
buildSkills() {
  const arr = this.user.skills.map(skill => {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: skill.name,
      id: skill.id,
      selected: skill.selected,
    });
  });
  return this.fb.array(arr);
}

buildLevels() {
  const arr = this.user.levels.map(level => {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: level.name,
      groupId: level.groupId,
      id: level.id,
      selected: level.selected,
    });
  });
  return this.fb.array(arr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. From what I see, the selected property still changes from initial boolean to string. I would have to do some post-processing based on type of this property. This is of course very simple, but a bit of unclean. Do you know of a way to have Forms API emit boolean when clicking radiobuttons?

Comment: @user776686, even I saw that. I'm trying to think of something. I'll update if I get a solution.